# Sequelize: Custom Method with Where statement

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have two Models, a `User` Model and a `Event` Model. A user can have many Events.

I am still learning Sequelize and I'm wondering if it's possible to create like a custom method that easily get's me the upcoming Events (column `date`), so that I can do something like

`User.getUpcomingEvents().then(() => {})`

I'm coming from Laravel and Eloquent, and that was pretty easy to achieve over there but I'm struggeling to do it in Sequelize and the documentation is still a bit confusing for me.

Appreciate your tips :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return events independent on the `userId` value, then you can use `classMethods` property when defining Model so that later you can call `Model.<methodName>`. In this case it would be `User.getUpcomingEvents()`

```
let User = sequelize.define('User', {
    // attributes...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        getUpcomingEvents: function(userId){
            return sequelize.models.Event.findAll({
                where: {
                    date: { $gt: new Date() },
                    UserId: userId // optional, if you want to return only events of given user
                }
            }).then(events => {
                return events;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Otherwise, if you want to return upcoming events of given user, you can also use classMethod that would get `userId` as parameter, or, you can use instance method so that you can use it like `userInstance.<methodName>` like `user.getUpcomingEvents()`

```
instanceMethods: {
    getUpcomingEvents: function() {
        return this.getEvents({ where: { date: { $gt: new Date() } } }).then(events => {
            return events;
        });
    }
}
```

Please read the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/?highlight=classMethods#expansion-of-models) concerning instance and class methods.